# How can i convert string to double ? I'm getting exception

Tags: c#

```
for(int i = 0; i < Rect.rectangles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Rect.rectangles[i].transform != null && Rect.rectangles[i].transform != "")
            {
                string firstNumber = Rect.rectangles[i].transform.Substring(18, 10);
                string secondNumber = Rect.rectangles[i].transform.Substring(7, 10);
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(firstNumber);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(secondNumber);
            }
        }
```

The first number is 0.49052715 and the Convert.ToDouble of a is fine.
But when it's getting to the line:

```
double b = Convert.ToDouble(secondNumber);
```

I'm getting exception:

FormatException: Unknown char: ,

But there is no any char/s at all the string in secondNumber is: 0.87142591

This is the whole string in transform: matrix(0.87142591,0.49052715,-0.49052715,0.87142591,0,0)

And i'm extracting the first two numbers: 0.49052715 and 0.87142591 and then trying to convert them to double. But getting the exception.

The code including the Rect.rectangles definition:

```
private void ParseSvgMap()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");

        Rect.rectangles = document.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
        {
            style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
            id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
            width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform")
        }).ToList();

        for(int i = 0; i < Rect.rectangles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Rect.rectangles[i].transform != null && Rect.rectangles[i].transform != "")
            {
                string firstNumber = Rect.rectangles[i].transform.Substring(18, 10);
                string secondNumber = Rect.rectangles[i].transform.Substring(7, 10);
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(firstNumber);
                double b = Convert.ToDouble(secondNumber);
                float degree = FindDegree(a, b);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float FindDegree(double a, double b)
    {
        float value = (float)((System.Math.Atan2(a, b) / System.Math.PI) * 180f);
        if (value < 0) value += 360f;

        return value;
    }

    public class Rect
    {
        public static List<Rect> rectangles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> style { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double? x { get; set; }
        public double? y { get; set; }
        public string transform { get; set; }
        public double degree { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetStyle(string styles)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
            string[] splitArray = styles.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Dictionary<string, string> style = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return style;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure `secondNumber` doesn't contain invalid character ? have you looked its value in the debugger ? because C#(normally) doesn't lie

Comment: Show us the definition of `Rect.rectangles`.

Comment: check the value of the `secondNumber` in debugger as @niceman said.

Comment: Ok i used a breakpoint and added a IF to check when the secondNumber contains "," and then break; and it does after some iterations stop at the break; and i see now in secondNumber "0.4655079," so i wonder how should i use the substring and what to change. I guess doing 18, 10 and 7, 10 is not a good idea it will not work in all cases. So how can i extract the two first numbers in any case ? Without any char/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like `.Substring(18, 10)` is hopelessly brittle and (as you have discovered) is an accident waiting to happen. Numbers aren't guaranteed to be the same length. Just look at the sample data you provided.

You should use something like a regex to extract the numbers from the strings before attempting to parse them.

```
var regex  = new Regex(@"matrix\((?<num>-?(?:\d|\.)+)(?:,(?<num>-?(?:\d|\.)+))*\)");
var data   = "matrix(0.87142591,0.49052715,-0.49052715,0.87142591,0,0)";
var values = regex
              .Matches(data)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .SelectMany(m => m.Groups["num"]
                                .Captures
                                .Cast<Capture>()
                                .Select(c=>c.Value))
              .Select(double.Parse)
              .ToList();
```

Then pick out the numbers you want with `values[0]` and `values[1]`.

Comment: Seems a bit like an overkill to me.

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner Possibly. I like my code to validate as many assumptions as possible, but I can see your POV

Comment: I understand that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its doomed to fail. 
I would use following regex:

```
        string test = "matrix(0.1234,0.23233433,0.34,-3343,-3.33)";
        Regex reg = new Regex("[-]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?");
        MatchCollection coll = reg.Matches(test);
```

Comment: Minus (`-`) signs?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method along the lines of :

```
 public double fixString(string incoming)
 {
  Double a;
  if(incoming.Contains(','))
  {
   string fixedNum = incoming.Remove(incoming.IndexOf(','));
   a = Convert.ToDouble(fixedNum);
   return a;
  }
  else
  {
   a = Convert.ToDouble(incoming);
   return a;
  }
 }
```